# how can i give sign (like change color or fa-up/fa-down) in php from mysql query result group by date

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

[image]

Expected: If osl is higher from date before, then echo 'fa-up'.

```
<?php $sql_nongadai_kol_kw2= mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT * FROM vw_nongadai_kanwil ORDER BY TGL_UPDATE DESC LIMIT 31"); ?> 
<?php foreach( $sql_nongadai_kol_kw2 as $print ){;
    $tanda ='tes';
    $osl_tes =$print['osl_total'];
    if ($osl_tes > $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>';}
    elseif ($osl_tes < $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>';}
    elseif ($osl_tes = $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-v"></i>';}
    else {$tanda = 'error';}
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $print['tgl_update'];?></th>
      <td align="right"><?php echo $tanda;?> - <?php echo number_format($print['osl_total']); ?></td>                            
    </tr>                                
<?php } ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate `$osl_tes` before foreach loop, within loop compare `$osl_tes` with `$print['osl_total']` and bind new value to `$osl_tes` :

```
<?php 
    $sql_nongadai_kol_kw2= mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT * FROM vw_nongadai_kanwil ORDER BY TGL_UPDATE DESC LIMIT 31"); 
    $osl_tes = 0; // or some other initial value
?> 
<?php foreach( $sql_nongadai_kol_kw2 as $print ){;
    $tanda ='tes';
    
    if ($print['osl_total'] > $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>';}
    elseif ($print['osl_total'] < $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>';}
    elseif ($print['osl_total'] = $osl_tes) {$tanda = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-v"></i>';}
    else {$tanda = 'error';}

    $osl_tes = $print['osl_total']; // bind new value
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $print['tgl_update'];?></th>
      <td align="right"><?php echo $tanda;?> - <?php echo number_format($print['osl_total']); ?></td>                            
    </tr>                                
<?php } ;?>
```

Comment: not work as i expected,
https://i.ibb.co/VYNRrRL/Capture3.jpg

Comment: work if query sort ASC (ORDER BY TGL_UPDATE ASC)